# git and visual studion references

Tags: git, visual-studio

I am using git with VS 2010. When I push my app to a repo and then fetch to a second computer all the references have to be re-established. This is because the references are embedded in the .proj file associated with the app.

I don't want to add the .proj file to .gitignore as this file needs to be kept synchronised.

Does anyone know how I can keep the references from being trashed with each push/fetch cycle

Answer (score 0):

Your references should not be device specific. When you clone your repository, you should not have to set any dependencies. Depending on what you are referencing, you have multiple options for this:

1. You can use NuGet packages (assuming the things you reference exist as NuGet packages or you can build them on your own) ([Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package), not sure if it works this way with VS2010)
2. You can reference other projects directly by making them part of your solution (and probably your repository, maybe as submodules or subtrees).
3. You can reference dlls that are also part of your project and checked into your repository. ([Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636(v=vs.100).aspx))

It would help to know if you a referencing third-party modules or modules also developed in-house.